# How to rename Tax option into GST in Magento 1.9 for Australian store

Tags: fatal-error

[image]
[image]

How  to  convert Tax option of  **Magento**  store into  **GST** option in **Magento 1.9**
1.Setting up tax (GST) in Magento
2.Show Grand Total Excl Tax. I include Incl Tax  in the Store
Invoice show both GST and Tax

Comment: Can you explain your issue clearly?.

Comment: Do you want to rename of **Tax** into **GST** ?

Comment: Yes  rename   Tax  into  **GST**   in   Australian  store

Answer (score 2):

Change in database at tax_calculation_rule table

```
https://prnt.sc/fw0cvw
```

This will change from Tax to GST at all locations

Comment: **Tax-calculation-rule** table  not show in the  **Database**

Comment: please check in all pages http://prntscr.com/fwkdts

Comment: Tester I checkt  tax_calultion_rule  show  GST . I think an edit to the question was in order. (Thanks for the suggestion.)

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: I search Tax-calcultion-rule  in Database . But In order review  show  Excl Tax  but I want show  Incl  Tax.                                                                                                                             Show Grand Total Wrong(Incl Tax)  Please see updated screenshot